# How to not have sum on pivot-table excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot-table excel spreadsheet.

As you can see below, I'm currently having sum in it.

[image]

What I would like is to have just, the value without summing.

I checked on the internet and so far, no luck.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: @Akina it works. Please put your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand Your problem correctly...

> to have just, the value without summin

It seems You have more than 1 value for any group (if not, the sum equals the value).

How to select 1 value from their list? Click the right tick of the field You need, select Properties and select another group function (MIN, for example).

Or drag whole field and move it to another window (Cols names for example).